# throw MissingPluginException No implementation found for method $method on channel $name

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

Anyone How To fix This Error when I try to click Login button on my `app` show this error

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'firebase_options.dart';
    
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.android);
    
      var email = 'sdf@gmail.com';
      var password = 'sdf';
    
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app());
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    
      if (auth != null) {
        print('success');
      } else {
        print('error');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which platform you are trying to run this? And which line triggers the error?